# Web api Client Call Error in Post method

Tags: asp.net-web-api

```
string Url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataUrl"];
DateTime trndate = DateTime.Now.Date;     
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Url);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(Url +"?id="+ trndate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).Result;
```

Above method worked Successfully but post method not worked.My Post method Calling Code is.

```
HttpClient Postclient = new HttpClient();
Postclient.BaseAddress = new Uri(Url);
Postclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
 Postclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
PostRemote rr = new PostRemote();
rr.id= 123;
rr.age= 38;
HttpResponseMessage postresponse = Postclient.PostAsJsonAsync(Url, rr).Result;
```

An exception occrued Error message is

`"Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**`

Comment: Yes it works.thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been faced many times, and just have a simple solution.

Go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager and Select Package Manager Console. Execute the following two commands:

```
uninstall-package newtonsoft.json -force

install-package newtonsoft.json
```

And add/change code in your `web.config`

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0"/>
 </dependentAssembly>
```